# Immediate redirect to the IdentityServer's login page from a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

Sample code provided in https://github.com/maxmantz/redux-oidc-example assumes that the user explicitly clicks on some kind of "Login" button to log on with OpenID Connect. This works fine if OpenID Connect is just one of the possible login types supported by an app.

However if we assume a pure single sign-on scenario where signing in with OpenID Connect is the only possible option, I'd think there's little sense in forcing the user perform an extra button click - rather, the SPA code should automatically redirect the user to the IdentityServer's login page.

So my question is what would be a proper way to perform such a redirect in a React / Redux / React Router SPA app? Would invoking

```
userManager.signInRedirect();
```

from a React component's `componentDidMount` be a good approach that will not break proper operation of react-router?

Just in case: the login page in question is obviously not a SPA's route in itself as it is hosted by IdentityServer, and also navigating to the login page might involve further redirects to an external identity provider (e.g. ADFS). So I believe the react-router's AuthFlow example does not apply here.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?